# Google + HTML Sign in not working on IE or Firefox

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-authentication

I'm working on a web app that uses client side authentication through the Google + API. Im using a modified example from Google that uses an HTML element with the app information and some Javascript to handle the response. In Chrome everything works great but in IE 9+ and Fierfox I cant get the authentication to kick in.

HTML:

```
<div id="signin-button" class="hide">
    <div class="g-signin"
         data-callback="loginFinishedCallback"
         data-clientid="{my client id}"
         data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"
         data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    >
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var profile, email;

        function loginFinishedCallback(authResult) {
            if (authResult) {
                if (authResult['error'] == undefined){
                    gapi.client.load('plus','v1', loadProfile);  // Trigger request to get the email address.
                } else {
                    console.log('An error occurred');
                    $( "#signin-button" ).removeClass( "hide" ).addClass( "show" );
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Empty authResult');  // Something went wrong
                $( "#signin-button" ).removeClass( "hide" ).addClass( "show" );
            }
        }

        /**
         * Uses the JavaScript API to request the user's profile, which includes
         * their basic information.
         */
        function loadProfile(){
            var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get( {'userId' : 'me'} );
            request.execute(loadProfileCallback);
        }

        function loadProfileCallback(obj) {
            profile = obj;
            email = obj['emails'].filter(function(v) {
                return v.type === 'account'; // Filter out the primary email
            })[0].value; // get the email from the filtered results, should always be defined.
            displayProfile(profile);
        }

        /**
         * Display the user's basic profile information from the profile object.
         */
        function displayProfile(profile){...}
    </script>
```

I should mention that I do not get any error on the console when the page loads in Firefox, IE, or Chrome.

Comment: I've had the same problem. I realized that the callback function provided in the google plus button simply isn't called and the program fails silently. I couldn't figure out the reason as the stack trace on Chrome, where the callback function is called, takes me into all kinds of messy Google code that is hard to de-crypt. So I don't know at which part Firefox and IE fail, but they do fail before calling the callback.

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved? I am stuck with this issue now. My Google + sign in button works perfectly on Chrome, but not on Firefox 35.0.1 and IE 11. The sign-in button is not at all getting displayed.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but for me it only occurred when the button was hidden initially (as part of a larger section of the page); when the section was later displayed, the google signin button would still be not visible, but only in Firefox and IE. I found that if, after I make the section appear, I manually size the iframe that google creates (because when hidden, it is 1px x 1px), that it google button appears in all tested browsers.

Comment: I also had similar issue with FF and IE. Can anyone help me out on this.

Comment: Your `div` in your html isn't closed, i.e. it doesn't have the matching `</div>` tag